# Is there a way to efficiently test a custom built extension on different Magento versions?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I am building an extension and I was wondering what the best way to test on different Magento versions, such as 1.9, 1.8, etc, would be.

Answer (score 1):

There is no silver bullet when it comes to testing your extension, what you can do from your side:

1. Make sure you follow all the [coding standards of Magento](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard).
2. Have an installed ready with sample data versions of Magento running for the major releases; 1.5,6,7,8,9
3. Provide very clear and readable error handling/messages, so the user can report back to you.
4. Keep updating your extension with any fixes to version issues and bugs. and always provide responses to feedback.
5. If you are able to publish your extension to the community, they are your best reviewer and tester.